# MATLAB parfor broadcast variable has wrong value

Tags: matlab, broadcast, parfor

In this minimal executable piece of code:

```
a = [];
workers = parpool('local',4);
someboolean = false;
parfor i = 1:4
    if someboolean % broadcast variable
        b = a(i); % ERROR
    else
        b = 0;
    end
end
```

... the value of someboolean is 'true' and the invalid line is executed resulting in the following error:

> Error using bugscript (line 4)
>       Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

The line number refers to the last nonparallel line and if the  `b = a(i)` assignment is removed the error disappears.

I have not been able to find others on the internet suffering from the same problem. Can anyone explain what is going on? I am using MATLAB R2015a.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because MATLAB performs static code analysis to determine which variables are needed each iteration through the loop by each worker. Since it sees that you are accessing `a(i)` inside of the loop, it attempts to fetch that value and make it available to the local worker *in case* it needs it. This behavior for [sliced variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html) is necessary to reduce the amount of data that is sent to each worker by only sending the data that is accessed by that iteration. This is particularly important if `a` had thousands of values and you only access one of them each iteration. You would only want to send the single entry in `a` rather than the entire array.

In your case, it tries to access `a(i)` to send to the worker and it's *this* process (and not the loop contents itself) that causes the error that you are seeing.

Have no fear, the value of the broadcasted variable, `someboolean`, *is* in fact `false` as you'd expect and you can confirm it with the following loop.

```
parfor i = 1:4
    disp(someboolean)
end
```

As a solution, I would simply pre-allocate `a` with values so that the slicing of `a` succeeds and that valid data is able to be sent to the worker (even if it's not used).

```
a = NaN(1,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in your code:

1. All the worker *processes* are trying to update `b` variable in the same time. This won't result in an error but will have undefined behavior. You won't know which process got to have the last update.
2. Your `a` array is not initialized to have at least 4 values and the workers try to access outside the boundaries of the array. This causes the error and you should start with initializing `a`.